# Stability of deformed planets

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, topology, complex-systems

Motivated by [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/692338/) and [first line of this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/692620/236734), I want to ask if we were describe the evolution of an orientable continuous **simply connected** physical body having mass distribution based on the ideas of [Dynamical systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_system) under the gravitational law, what configurations would look  like the [attractors and repellors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attractor)? How could the answer change if we increased the [genus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_(mathematics)) of the surface?

To clear ambiguity, I am assuming the interior of surface being filled uniformly with some constant mass per volume density $\rho(x)=m$

Comment: I'm a bit concerned that the question maybe ill posed somewhere, please let me know if there is any issue in the framing and I'll fix it. Besides that, intuition tells me that the least energy state should be a sphere ( i guess?)

Comment: Related: [Can a nonspherical planet exist and can it be habitable?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/8772/47045), [Is a ring planet possible?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/119904/47045), [So You Thought You Knew What Spinning Planets Look Like?](https://www.science20.com/robert_inventor/so_you_thought_you_knew_what_planets_look_like_shapes_of_rapidly_spinning_planets-155538).