# Why are triangular orbits not possible in our universe?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion

Why are triangular orbits not possible in our universe?

Comment: I wouldn't say they're impossible, only that I know of no equation of motion that yields triangular solutions in this context. Could you say why you focus on triangular trajectories?

Comment: The answer is pretty much the same as https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/692338/

Comment: If you get very close to a black hole, orbits can become very strange looking, including some with somewhat triangular features.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Triangular orbits would have sharp corners. This implies sudden changes of direction, which in turn implies sudden changes of velocity and therefore accelerations. Acceleration is defined by

$$\text {acceleration}=\frac{\text{change in velocity}}{\text{time taken to change}}$$

The top line of the fraction has a finite magnitude, but the bottom line is immeasurably small if the corner is sharp and the body is moving at a finite speed. So the acceleration at the corners is infinite. An infinite acceleration needs the orbiting body to be acted upon by an infinite force. What could supply such a force?

Answer (score 1):

A triangle has corners, three of 'em.   At those corners, acceleration
must be high, to alter the direction of a moving object abruptly.  So, there are three high-force (F= mA) events in each orbit.   To the best
of my knowledge, there are no central forces consistent with an
isotropic (same-physics-in-all-places) universe that can exert
such force.   One could have three reflectors and propel a rubber ball
in a triangular 'orbit', but the only way a central force would
have that effect, is with an  equilateral triangle orbit around a center
of constant potential energy except with a large  potential up-step at
some radius R; this is called a 'spherical square well' in
quantum mechanics.

Expected central force fields in this three dimensional universe
(Yukawa potentials) are  exponential in radius R, times R^(-2).
That doesn't create any region with straight-line trajectories in multiple directions, so is inconsistent with triangle orbits.